# How can create pdf file in cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using "tcpdf" vendor file in cakephp 2.X but it is not looking good view. I want every html tag convert properly in pdf file. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the a blog for you. its will be help you to find your problem.

Read the following blog

[Generating PDFs with CakePHP](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/04/08/generating-pdfs-with-cakephp/)

You will be find a [link for demostration](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/plugins/cake_pdf) of different PDF file generator.

May be I help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have built my own plugins in the past using MPDF, they worked for years, kinda slow on some environments. Recently, I switched to WkHtmlToPdf and love it. I built my own plugin then a few weeks later realized that one already existed. I would recommend using this plugin by Friends of Cake: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf

A lot of the contributor for Friends of Cake are also Core CakePHP developers, so its usually very well coded, tested & documented.

This plugin also works with several PDF generation engines, which is a nice touch!

Answer (score 0):

I am using wkhtmltopdf for few years and it's working very good, quality of PDF you can get from a html is very good, I am also using the cakephp for PDF generation.

I am running this command from cakephp controller

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf  < SOURCE_HTML_PATH/URL > < DESTINATION_PDF_PATH> ");
```

You can install stable version wkhtmltopdf for your linux distribution from this link

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html#stable